# How many processes and threads will the following C code generate?

Tags: c, multithreading, process

Consider the following code written in C language. At the time of execution of `while(1);` how many processes and threads we are going to have, respectively?

```
int main(void) 
{
   int i;
   for (i=0; i<3; i++)
      fork();
   while(1);
}
```

Comment: You aren't creating any additional threads, only additional processes. So if we agree that each process has one thread running `main`, then the number of threads is equal to the number of processes. As for how many processes you have, the easy way to find out is to put a `printf` before the `while(1)` and see. You may wish to print the process ID, and parent process ID (from `getpid` and `getppid` respectively) since that will allow you to recreate the entire process tree.

Comment: Thanks @user3386109, the fork creates 8 additional process. I was not sure about the number of threads. It's right to say that each process has one thread?

Comment: Yes, as far as I know, each process has one thread.

Comment: Sounds like a homework question.

Answer (score 0):

<s>A process will always have a main thread, otherwise it will not be able to schedule itself into the thread queue which allows the physical processor to execute instruction.</s>

Also, there's no real limit to how many process/thread you can spawn as it is limited by how much memory you have on your system.

Your following code, assuming fork does not fail, excluding your parent process, will spawn 3 process and for each process 1 thread

That means, including your parent process, 4 process, and 4 thread.

see David Schwartz answer

Comment: Your answer does not take into account the actions of the spawned processes.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to tell is to add this line before the `while(1)` loop:

```
printf("I am process: %d, my parent is %d\n", (int) getpid(), (int) getppid());
```

Example output:

> I am process: 4365, my parent is 8358
>   I am process: 4366, my parent is 4365
>   I am process: 4367, my parent is 4365
>   I am process: 4369, my parent is 4365
>   I am process: 4368, my parent is 4366
>   I am process: 4370, my parent is 4366
>   I am process: 4371, my parent is 4367
>   I am process: 4372, my parent is 4368

That's 8 processes in total, each with a single thread.

What happened? 8358 was my shell. When I executed this code, it created process 4365. That's one.

4365 created three processes, one when it had two more loops to go (4366), one when it had one more loop to go (4367), and one on its final loop (4369). That's three more, so now we're up to four.

The one it created with two loops to go (4366) created two more processes, one when it had one loop to go (4368) and one when it had no loops to go (4370). That's two more, so now we're up to six.

We still have two processes with one loop to go, one created by the first process (4367) and one created by the second process (4368). Each of those creates one more process (4371 and 4372). That's two more, so now we're up to 8.